# How does Android define a screen resolution as long?

Tags: android, screen-resolution

With Android, you can define different resources for different phone attribute by naming res directories appropriately.  I need to be able to support different layouts for `480x800` and `480x854`.  I figured I could have one set of resources stored in the layout-hdpi-v4 directory and another in layout-long-hdpi-v4.  However, both resolution seem to think that they are long (at least based on the emulator, which I understand may not reflect devices accurately).

Is there another way in which I can distinguish between the two resolutions/aspect ratios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [screen size qualifier](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#AlternateResources), though its use is deprecated and recommended to not be used:

`layout-800x480`,`layout-854x480`

Otherwise, it doesn't look like there is a supported way in resource naming that can differentiate the two resolutions, besides using flexible layouts to expand into the extra screen space.

Comment: Note, the hdpi qualifier will trump the res qualifier by itself.  So, if you decide to go this unrecommended route, you will need to make it layout-hdpi-854x480. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to determine the screen size in code, [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) will help

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

You can look at the fields `widthPixels` and `heightPixels`.

However, read too the [Best Practices for Screen Independence](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence).

Comment: I'm familiar with all that stuff. It's a unique case where I'm porting an iPhone app that requires a view to be aligned along the bottom.  At the same time my layout needs to extend longer than the screen on the 480x800 to avoid having the background resize to a different aspect ratio. Otherwise, the use of layout_alignParentBottom would do the trick.