# How to differentiate layout for 480 * 800 and 480 * 854 screen resolutions in android?

Tags: android, screen, resolution

In one of the application I need to make sure that UI components will be placed at proper position in all the screen resolution devices. I have gone through the support multiple screen resolutions tutorial on android developer site. Based on that it seems I may have to create separate layout files for small, normal and large screen devices. Now, the issue in this is that even in large screens there are different resolutions such as 480 * 800 and 480 * 854. In the screen the components gets misplaced slightly. I have set top margin as 100 dip then for 480 * 800 it appears properly but for 480 * 854 it is misplaced slightly.

Can someone let me know how to handle this now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both the resolutions are considered under the layout-long, so  you have to set the layout as per the device's height and width manually.

As per my view this is the best solution . I applied the same solution for my application .

### Example

```
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        height = dm.heightPixels;
        width = dm.widthPixels;

        if (height == 854 || width == 480) 
        {
              // Your view 
        }
        else
        {
              // Your VIew
        }
```

You have to check the above condition in onCreate() method of acivity..

Comment: hi, would this be the best solution still after 6 years? I'm having the same issue thus my question

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible to differ between WVGA854 and WVGA800 by using:

res/drawable-hdpi-long/
res/drawable-hdpi-notlong/

but i would definately recommend you to design the layouts so that it is robust enough to use one set of layouts for those two screens. It will be too much work to maintain/test of you can't design one layout in that case.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But what you said is suitable for images. Can we also do the same with layouts such as layout-large-long and layout-large-notlong.

Comment: sorry, you can do the same, i.e. res/layout-hdpi-long, and res/layout-hdpi-notlong

Comment: If I create those folders inside res it gives me compile time error. Have you used this way in any of your application?

Comment: ah sorry, it should be res/layout-long-hdpi and res/layout-notlong-hdpi. Chirag is probably right, i.e. both layouts are considered long. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893838/how-does-android-define-a-screen-resolution-as-long