# how to define seperate layouts for Motorola Atrix and Motorola Droid

Tags: android, motorola

Hi

I need to define separate layout's for Motorola Droid and Motorola Atrix .I tried with drawable-hdpi and layout-long ,layout-large-long but both seems to relay on layout-long .How to define a separate layout's supporting both device.Hence the layout that written for Droid has more empty space at the bottom for Atrix.In my manifest file i have android:largeScreens="true"  android:anyDensity="true".

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

The Droid has a hardware keyboard ... the Atrix does not.

qwerty: Device has a hardware qwerty keyboard, whether it's visible to the user or not

So for the Droid:

```
  /drawable-qwerty/
  /layout-qwerty/
```

Atrix:

```
  /drawable/
  /layout/
```

etc..

[Dev Res Link - Scroll down to Primary text input method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2)

and if you don't understand these folder structures please look at:

[Best Match Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

Comment: I need to define different layouts as I said ,I hope the below method shall be efficient if(displaymetrics.heightPixels>900){ setContentView (R.layout.AtrixScreen) } else { setContentView (R.layout.DroidScreen) } ,any comments ?

Comment: Yes /layout-qwerty/ & /layout/ just like I said above. Have you tried it?

Comment: thanks Blundell for your response ,but what happens for devices which is of droid type but doesn't have hardware keyboard.I need my app to support not only those two device but most of the device available in market

Comment: For all other devices, if they don't fall into the /drawable-qwerty/ category they will fallback to the default /drawable/ category. You should read a bit of that page I linked you :-) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 0):

Check the following post which may help you [How does Android define a screen resolution as long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893838/how-does-android-define-a-screen-resolution-as-long)